# How to group/section realtime Firestore data in Recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I have been able to use this [library](https://github.com/jaychang0917/SimpleRecyclerView) (SimpleRecyclerview) to section my real-time data from Firebase Firestore inside my recyclerview. It works as expected, but I haven't gotten it to update the recyclerview in real-time as the data changes inside the Firestore database. I can achieve this using a normal recyclerview but I need the data to be sectioned, hence the library. I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38513589/sectioned-recyclerview-with-different-layouts) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36514278/sectioned-recyclerview) on stackoverflow but none of the posts address sectioning real-time data that is constantly changing.

Here are my codes:

My simple cell class -

```
public class UpcomingCell extends SimpleCell<MatchModel, UpcomingCell.ViewHolder>{


        public UpcomingCell(@NonNull MatchModel item) {
            super(item);
        }

        @Override
        protected int getLayoutRes() {
            return R.layout.item_livescore;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        protected UpcomingCell.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, @NonNull View cellView) {
            return new UpcomingCell.ViewHolder(cellView);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UpcomingCell.ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Context context, Object payload)            {
    
            holder.visitorTeamName.setText(getItem().getVisitorTeam());
            ...
            ...
            ...
                    }

        public class ViewHolder extends SimpleViewHolder {

            TextView liveTextView;

            public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                liveTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.liveTextView);
                ...
                ...
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Recycler Header method -

```
public void addRecyclerHeaders(){
        SectionHeaderProvider<MatchModel> sectionHeaderProvider = new SimpleSectionHeaderProvider<MatchModel>() {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public View getSectionHeaderView(@NonNull MatchModel item, int position) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_group_header,null,false);
                TextView headerTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.headerTitle);
                TextView headerCountry = view.findViewById(R.id.headerCountry);
                ImageView leagueLogo = view.findViewById(R.id.leagueImage);
                headerCountry.setText(item.getGroupCountry());
                headerTitle.setText(item.getGroupTitle());
                return view;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isSameSection(@NonNull MatchModel item, @NonNull MatchModel nextItem) {
                return item.getGroupID() == nextItem.getGroupID();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isSticky() {
                return true;
            }
        };

        simpleRecyclerView.setSectionHeader(sectionHeaderProvider);
    }
```

Bind data method -

```
private void bindData(){
        bindStandings = finalData;
        Collections.sort(bindStandings, new Comparator<MatchModel>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(MatchModel o1, MatchModel o2) {
                return o1.getGroupID() - o2.getGroupID();
            }
        });


        for (MatchModel matchModel : bindStandings){
            UpcomingCell upcomingCell = new UpcomingCell(matchModel);
            upcomingCell.setOnCellClickListener(new SimpleCell.OnCellClickListener<MatchModel>() {
                @Override
                public void onCellClicked(@NonNull MatchModel item) {

                }
            });

            cells.add(upcomingCell);
        }
        simpleRecyclerView.addCells(cells);
    }
```

And this is the method I use in getting data from Firestore -

```
private void getAllData(){

        standings = new ArrayList<>();

        Group groupA = new Group(0, "Premier League", "England", 8);
        ...
        ...
        ...

        Date todayDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String todayString = formatter.format(todayDate);

        Query query = firebaseFirestore.collection("fixtures")
                .whereEqualTo("real_date", todayString)
                .orderBy("league_id")
                .orderBy("timestamp");

        query.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                if(error != null){
                    noMatchTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    
                }else{

                    standings.clear();
                    finalData.clear();
                    bindStandings.clear();
                    cells = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(DocumentChange documentChange : value.getDocumentChanges()){

                        if(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(documentChange.getDocument().get("league_id"))) == 8){
                            MatchModel plModel = documentChange.getDocument().toObject(MatchModel.class);
                            plModel.setGroup(groupA);
                            standings.add(plModel);
                        }

                        ...
                        ...
                        ...
                                               

                    }
                    noMatchTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    finalData = standings;
                    bindData();

                }
            }


        });
    }
```

Please can anyone let me know how to use the library to achieve this, or is there a better/easier way to section real-time Firestore data in a recyclerview? Thank you.